# Deploy Umbraco website

Tags: database, deployment, umbraco

I've been working with Umbraco to create my first website.

So far I almost completed the framework of my website and now I'm thinking about how to move it to my server. My idea is to upload my website when the framework is ready, and then create the contents remotely. I'm updating an existing website, which means that the host server already hosts one website, which I have to replace with the one I'm creating with Umbraco.

How can I do the deploy of the website? 
Have to install Umbraco at the host server? 
What about the Database?

I will use the database of the host server. I want to upload my new website, but still keep the old one in case something goes wrong. Please keep in mind that I'm a total newbie at this and have never uploaded any website. Would really appreciate your help!

Thanks in advance, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the capabilities of your hosting provider. Create a new folder on the server and place there your Umbraco files.
And change the IIS webroot location to the new folder. (by changing it to the old location your old site is back again)

And you need to backup your local database, and restore on the database server from your hosting provider. and configure the connectionstring.

At low end hosting providers you can often not restore database backups.
one option may be to generate a SQL script including data. (often you need to change the database schema,user to the one you own on the hosting provider) Otherwise, start with a clean database and import your Umbraco items with a Umbraco package.